# Input submit name is not being posted

Tags: jquery, html, forms, submit

I have a form with one input field and submit button. I know the name of the button can be submitted but for some reason, it isn't being posted to the server.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("form").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log($(this).serialize());
      return false;
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
<div class="a">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input name="projectName" type="text">
</div>
<div class="b">
  <input name="newProject" value="Save Project" type="submit"></div> 
</form>
<p>"newProject" field from submit input is not being posted</p>
```

The only thing visible by doing `print_r($_POST)` is `Array([projectName] => "")` but the form name "newProject" is not visible or even being sent.

Here is a fiddle demonstrating it: https://jsfiddle.net/bosLyn1w/

Why is this happening and how can I submit the name of the submit input?

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you are expecting-- your code works exactly as it is written.  If you want to make some sort of [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) request using jQuery, then it would best be placed in your `submit` handler.  Also, in my opinion, you could have posted the relevant JavaScript in your question rather than relying on users to click away to your fiddle-- just a courtesy to the community.

Comment: @anied fixed, I added a code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('form').on('click', 'input[type=submit]', function(e) {
$(this.form).data('clicked', this.name);      
$('.pVal').html($(this.form).serialize()+ ' <br> '+this.name+'=' +this.value);
console.log($(this.form).serialize());
return false;
});
});
</script>
<form method="post">
<div class="a">
<label>Name</label>
<input name="projectName3" type="text">
</div>
<div class="b">
<input name="newProject4" class="newProject" value="Save Project" type="submit"></div>  
</form>
<p class="pVal"> -- Please put the both fields value here ---</p>
```

Comment: Please use this code for to see out "newProject" from the input form